# Multiple Submit Buttons Security Risk

Tags: java, security, jsp, struts2, ognl

For some reasons, I need to create a form with two submit buttons which are going to call different actions after submission.

I found the following example in [Multiple Submit Buttons](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14289#content/view/14289):

```jsp
<s:form method="post" action="mySubmitAction">
    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    <s:submit value="Clear" action="myClearAction"/>
</form>
```

As my project is using Struts 2.3.16.3, `struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled = true` is needed.

However, is there any risk to enable it back in struts 2.3.16.3?
Will it share the same security problem in 2.3.15.2?

If yes, would you mind providing some alternatives to make the multiple submit buttons work on single form? `if-else` solution is not preferred.

Comment: You could use javascript for multiple buttons and direct your data to actions like that. It is more work then just using the struts.xml. As with regard to the security issue: Can you be more specific on the security issue?

Comment: The security issue is stated in [https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-018.html](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-018.html). When using `action:` prefix in Struts 2 before 2.3.15.3, under certain conditions this can be used to bypass security constraints.

Comment: To use javascript for multiple buttons, do you mean to fire onclick event and change the action name dynamically? Or do you mean to use ajax to call it?

Comment: Ok, then it should be fixed in 2.3.16.3, so no problem there.

Comment: Use either a script with just a direct call to an action, or change the action name dynamically. The benefit of JS in such a style is mainly when you have form validation anyway (or if you want to use AJAX style pages for example combining it with angular JS)

Comment: thanks for your help, and i will implement it by using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vulnerabilities discovered in versions Struts 2.0.0 - Struts 2.3.15.2 related to the OGNL injection attack. In fact the `action:` prefix opens a door for this kind of attacks.

Previously it's discovered in [S2-016](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-016.html), the fixed version was [2.3.15.1](http://struts.apache.org/docs/version-notes-23151.html). Lately [S2-018](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-018.html) was introduced and they disabled the `action:` prefix. Recommended upgrade was [2.3.15.3](http://struts.apache.org/docs/version-notes-23153.html).

This means that using `action:` prefix is discouraged and you can enable in on your own risk. In [S2-019](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-019.html) the DMI was disabled by default too, so you can't use `method:` prefix because it works only if DMI is enabled.

These restrictions made side effect on multiple button usage where `action` or `method` attributes used to bind `s:submit` buttons to the action other than in the `s:form` action attribute. To use multiple buttons to execute its own methods of the action class you can pass a parameter that holds a method name. It could be a hidden field or submit field, etc.

When `execute` method is called this information should be already available and you can use Java to call the method by the name. Another approach is most popular to use javascript to modify the form's action attribute in the onclick event handler before the form is submitted.

```jsp
<s:form name="myForm" method="post" action="mySubmitAction" >
    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    <s:submit value="Clear" onclick="myClearAction()"/>
</form>  
<script>
   function myClearAction(){
     document.forms["myForm"].action = "<s:url action='myClearAction' />";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, and i will implement it by using javascript